# What is the variable visibility error in this code?

Tags: php, inheritance

I am a newbie to OOP in PHP and I am trying to create a small MVC structure for my website but I am stuck on an error which I am not able to figure out. My code is similar to the one given below :

```
class a
{
    protected $b = "b";

    protected function c()
    {
        return $this->b;
    }
}

class d extends a
{
    public function e()
    {
        parent::c();
    }
}

$f = new d();
var_dump($f->e());
```

---

The output of this code is null, which I can't figure out !

In my original code I am storing my username and password in class 'a' and returning a PDO object in function 'c'.

What is the error here ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're getting the value of `parent::c()`, but you don't do anything with it. Use a return statement.

Comment: Thanx, that solved it!  
P.S. somewhere i was afraid i had done a silly mistake !